# My python code doesn't work (it shows nothing)

Tags: python

```py
import csv 
import hashlib 
from sqlite3 import register_converter 
def dictionary_attack(password_hash): 
    dictionary = {"letmein","password","12345","fotball"} 
    password_found = False 
    for dictionary_value in dictionary: 
        hashed_value = (hashlib.md5(dictionary_value)).hexdigest() 
        if hashed_value == password_hash: 
            password_found = True 
            recovered_passvord = dictionary_value 
    if password_found == True: 
        (f"found math for the hashed value  /n") 
        (f"password recovered:{recovered_passvord}") 
    else: 
        (f"password was not found") 
def main(): 
    password_hash = raw_input("entered hashed value : ") 
    dictionary_attack(password_hash)
```

Comment: Well you're not printing anything so...

Comment: You should expand in your question, but... aren't you missing print before those formatted strings between parens?

Comment: Tnks bro. But what if I want to use Sha 256 portocol

Comment: You know. My teacher gives me this homework. He gave me a csv file that contains some hashed numbers and wants to show the numbers in the terminal. I don't know what to do.

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need you to ask your question a little more effectively. For example: how can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: What were you expecting your code to "show"? Why are you importing unnecessary modules?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't even call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have print statements.

```py
print(f"found math for the hashed value  /n") 
print(f"password recovered:{recovered_passvord}") 
    else: 
        print(f"password was not found")
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I said I have a csv file that contains some hashed numbers and I want to write a program that shows me the numbers.